# fizz buzz code not accomplishing what I expected

Tags: javascript

Why is this code not working for a fizz buzz question? I was trying out how hacker rank works. The parameters given are:

```
if n is a multiple of both 3 and 5 print FizzBuzz
if n is a multiple of 3 but not 5 print Fizz
if n is a multiple of 5 but not 3 print Buzz
if n is not a multiple of both 3 and 5 print n
```

If I assign `n` beforehand and run the function it logs the proper expected output but when I run the test case on hacker rank they all fail.

EDIT: I tried a comment suggestion but still doesn't work it just adds  `FizzBuzz` n times to the results array.

```js
let results = []

function fizzBuzz(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0) {
      results.push('FizzBuzz')
    } else if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 != 0) {
      results.push('Fizz')
    } else if (n % 5 == 0 && n % 3 != 0) {
      results.push('Buzz')
    } else if (n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 != 0) {
      results.push(n)
    }
  }
  console.log(results)
}

function main() {
  const n = parseInt(prompt("Enter number").trim(), 10);
  fizzBuzz(n);
}
main()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-fizzbuzz-algorithm-in-javascript) answer your question

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain the link is broken

Comment: [Check This link](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-fizzbuzz-algorithm-in-javascript)

Comment: you shouldn't need the `!=` in your `else if`s and that final should just be an `else`

Comment: @Pete yeah i know i just added that to make my code look exactly like the parameters.

Comment: @seriously could you provide the problem's statement?

Comment: It's probably not working due to the way you assign `n` - perhaps that doesn't work when run in hacker rank or whatever you are running it in

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain i edited my code with your suggestion. Still doesn't work. Read the edit for a better explanation.

Comment: Are you supposed to loop? Seems kinda weird that they'd have you loop when `n` stays the same in each iteration. Or are you supposed to be testing `i`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i thought the same to but someone suggested a method that could work which includes looping but that doesn't work too.

Comment: I think instead of `n`  that should `i` inside for loop.

Comment: @Asraf no it shouldn't but why did you say that?

Comment: @seriously for the fizzbuzz problems it's mostly they give a range, let say 1 to n and you need to print `fizz` or `fizzbuzz` in every iteration. and if your case is only `n` then you don't need to use loop. Can you please add sample input and output to the question then it'll be easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your using the wrong variable inside the loop. (You need to use `i` isntead of `n`) Let's see why:

n is the variable the user provides, it is a parameter of the function `fizzBuzz` and it will stay the same for the whole execution of the function. The only point at which n changes/is defined is on user input. So when you check in your loop if n is divisible by 3 you are (in each end every iteration of your loop checking if n (the user input) is divisible by 5 - n WONT change.

i on the other hand is the iteration variable. i will change after each iteration (by increasing by 1) it will increase until it reaches n. If you check if i is divisible you start by checking 0 on your first iteration, on your second iteration you will check 1, on your thrid 2 and so on.

Always be sure what your variables represent and what variables to use for what purpouse (that's why giving variables descriptive names is so important)

Below your fixed code (just replaced n with i):

```js
let results = []

function fizzBuzz(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
      results.push('FizzBuzz')
    } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
      results.push('Fizz')
    } else if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 != 0) {
      results.push('Buzz')
    } else if (i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
      results.push(i)
    }
  }
  console.log(results)
}

function main() {
  const n = parseInt(prompt("Enter number").trim(), 10);
  fizzBuzz(n);
}
main()
```

Comment: The last `else if` statement,should be a simple `else` without an condition.

Comment: @tjarbo This "improvement" won't do anything except distract from the actual problem that causes the unwanted behaviour - would it be cleaner and nicer to to an else? - certainly. But is it wrong to use else if()? - no ...... (I would write the whole if else block differently, but the more I change the more difficult it gets to spot which is the "fix" and which just me making the code more readable/nicer.